# How to define generic java method that returns List

Tags: java, generics

I want to create method which takes single object and returns same type of objects. It is like;

```
public List<Apple> createApples(Apple apple){
    .....
}
```

I tried several ways but It always gives error.

```
public List<T> createApples(T apple)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a generic method.

```
public <T> List<T> createApples(T apple)
```

Comment: I don't get why I must write "<T>" before "List<T>" but It works.

Comment: @hellzone That's the syntax for writing a generic method. You are saying that the method is parameterized with the type T. The type will usually be inferred by the actual parameter's type. You can also tell the compiler the actual type by doing createApples<Apple>() when you call it (I think this is the syntax, but I've never used it so I don't remember it :S).